# Error compiling libfreenect stack

Tags: ubuntu, ros-fuerte, rosmake, ubuntu-precise, libfreenect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I am currently trying to rosmake the [freenect_stack](http://ros.org/wiki/freenect_stack) Piyush is maintaining. I downloaded the drivers on the desktop in the lab and they compiled fine. However, when I tried to compile on the laptop in the lab rosmake gave me the following errors (specifically in the libfreenect stack):

```
 [rosmake-0] Starting >>> libfreenect [ make ]                                   
[ rosmake ] All 28 lines
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  mkdir -p build/OpenKinect-libfreenect-9ab2c20/build
  cd build/OpenKinect-libfreenect-9ab2c20/build && cmake ../ 
  -- Operating system is Linux
  -- Got System Processor x86_64
  -- Linux x86_64 Detected
  -- libfreenect will be installed to /usr/local
  -- Headers will be installed to /usr/local/include/libfreenect
  -- Libraries will be installed to /usr/local/lib64
  CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
  Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
  GLUT_Xi_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)
      linked by target "glpclview" in directory /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/freenect_stack/libfreenect/build/OpenKinect-libfreenect-9ab2c20/examples
      linked by target "glview" in directory /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/freenect_stack/libfreenect/build/OpenKinect-libfreenect-9ab2c20/examples
      linked by target "hiview" in directory /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/freenect_stack/libfreenect/build/OpenKinect-libfreenect-9ab2c20/examples
      linked by target "regview" in directory /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/freenect_stack/libfreenect/build/OpenKinect-libfreenect-9ab2c20/examples
      linked by target "cppview" in directory /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/freenect_stack/libfreenect/build/OpenKinect-libfreenect-9ab2c20/wrappers/cpp
  GLUT_Xmu_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)
      linked by target "glpclview" in directory /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/freenect_stack/libfreenect/build/OpenKinect-libfreenect-9ab2c20/examples
      linked by target "glview" in directory /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/freenect_stack/libfreenect/build/OpenKinect-libfreenect-9ab2c20/examples
      linked by target "hiview" in directory /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/freenect_stack/libfreenect/build/OpenKinect-libfreenect-9ab2c20/examples
      linked by target "regview" in directory /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/freenect_stack/libfreenect/build/OpenKinect-libfreenect-9ab2c20/examples
      linked by target "cppview" in directory /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/freenect_stack/libfreenect/build/OpenKinect-libfreenect-9ab2c20/wrappers/cpp
  LIBUSB_1_LIBRARY
      linked by target "freenect" in directory /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/freenect_stack/libfreenect/build/OpenKinect-libfreenect-9ab2c20/src
      linked by target "freenectstatic" in directory /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/freenect_stack/libfreenect/build/OpenKinect-libfreenect-9ab2c20/src
  
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package libfreenect written to:
[ rosmake ]    /root/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121031-140959/libfreenect/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< libfreenect [FAIL] [ 0.10 seconds ]                    
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package libfreenect. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                            
[ rosmake ] Built 1 packages with 1 failures.                                   
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                         
[ rosmake ] /root/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121031-140959
```

Does anyone know what these errors are from? Thanks for all the help with these compiling issues.

Kind Regards,
Martin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47217/error-compiling-libfreenect-stack/) by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 464 on 2012-10-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The package has not compiled locally on your machine, so the the launch results in the above error. Try the system package ros-fuerte-freenect-stack. See http://www.ros.org/wiki/freenect_stack

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2012-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0